# How can i look at image size in Visual Studio?

Tags: image, visual-studio, size

I have some images in project.

[image]

I want to see size of image without any code. I want see to the height and width of image. For example in properties of image I see next information:

[image]

How can i look at image size in Visual Studio? Can I see it with help of VS?

I have an installed Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017.

Comment: I believe this isn't possible. You will have to check file size through file explorer

Comment: @AbdulSamad, thanks, but I think it is possible. But how...i don't remember where I  was see it

Comment: @AbdulSamad, I find it. It inside window of opened image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open image from project inside Visual Studio. Click button <kbd>Show or hide the properties window</kbd>

[image]
Maybe it will be useful.